# VSCode PowerShell Debugger - How to pass command line arguments to the PowerShell process

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

With the standard Code terminal I can pass command line arguments to its PowerShell executable like this, and it works as shown [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/s4l2fW0.png):

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
 "General": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
    "args": [
        "-noexit",
      "-command",
      "Get-ChildItem",
  ]
 }
},
```

I am trying to do the same thing with the "PowerShell Extension" Terminal that is used when Debugging. According to VSCode documentation,[Configuring the task/debug profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-the-taskdebug-profile), the `terminal.integrated.automationProfile.<platform>` key can be used to send command line arguments to that terminal, I tried:

```
"terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
    "args": [
        "-noexit",
      "-command",
      "Get-ChildItem",
  ]
 },
```

It seems to be ignored or perhaps I am not doing it right. I really need to send arguments to the executable not the script, as I can do that  in **launch.json** with `"args": []`.

Of course `Get-ChildItem` makes no sense, it was just an example. For example, as it stands one of the arguments the debugger is using is `noprofile`, there are times it makes sense to test against profiles, even pseudo ones.